# Is there a direct funtion to count numbers inside a string?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a string that contains digits inside. For example, `"adf20j83n,m3jh2k9"`. Is there a direct way to count the number of digits inside the string. As in my example, it should give me `"7"` as an output.

Also, I have tried `RegExp` but it's not working in VBScript in QTP.

Btw, I'm not looking for loops and stuff like that. Just a direct way, or a suggestion to make this `RegExp` work in QTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need to create the COM object via its ProgId:

```
Dim re
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "\d"
re.Global = True

MsgBox "Digits: " & re.Execute("adf20j83n,m3jh2k9").Count
```

Output:

```
Digits: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's techically what you said but it's a good way nonetheless

Try using this function:

```
Public Sub CountNumeric(ByVal input As String)

    Dim numericCount As Integer = 0

    For Each c As Char In input
        If Char.IsDigit(c) Then numericCount += 1
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Number of numerics : {0}", numericCount)

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
You could also try this:

```
Dim charColl As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input , "^\d+$")
Console.WriteLine(charColl.Count.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but I was looking if there is a direct function similar to RegExp in VBScript. I don't know why this is not working VBScript QTP. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Added another function which might me more your thing

Comment: Neither VBScript nor a useful pattern.